# Notepad regular expression no coge parentesis

Tags: regex, notepad++

Tengo unas dudas a cerca de notepad++ Cuando intento reemplazar cualquiera de cadena de caracteres entre inicio y fin uso el modo regular expression para reemplazar por ejemplo un contenido de caracteres: inicio caractesres.... fin
por algo()
Usaría la siguiente expresion regular

Find

> inicio([\w\W]+?)fin

Replace

> susitucion()

El problema es que normalmente la parte correspondiente al parentesis no me lo coge es decir me reemplazaría la cadena que he escogido por

> susitucion y no por susitucion()

Comment: ya probaste a escapar los paréntesis? `sustitucion\(\)`

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar un ejemplo de aquello que tienes y deseas lograr?

Comment: Notepad++ desde cierta versión utiliza expresiones regulares *Boost* en lugar de *PCRE*. Las expresiones regulares *Boost* necesitan escapar los paréntesis en la sustitución, ya que se pueden utilizar para otras cosas, como sustituciones condicionales. Simplemente escapalos como sugiere Ruslan Lopez

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++, desde la versión 6.0, utiliza la librería *[Boost](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.regex)* (en lugar de [PCRE](https://www.pcre.org/)) para las expresiones regulares.

> The release build of Notepad++ is built with Boost.
>
> Since Notepad++ version 6.0, the build of SciLexer.dll that is
>   distributed uses features from Boost's Boost.Regex library.
>
> [Fuente](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus)

Las expresiones regulares Boost necesitan escapar los paréntesis en la sustitución, ya que se pueden utilizar para otras cosas, como [sustituciones condicionales](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replaceconditional.html).

Si quieres usar los paréntesis de manera literal, tienes que escaparlos con el caracter contrabarra `\`